# Why does Elasticsearch have a terrible performance indexing small amount of data inside docker?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I try to configure django app with elasticsearch inside docker using docker-compose. Building of a small index takes around 15 minutes inside docker. The same command executes in 30 seconds if I run it outside docker.

Here is my docker-compose.yml which was based on [the official docker installation guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html):

```
version: '3'


services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: compose/local/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ../..:/var/www/chesno
    env_file:
      - ../../.env.local
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch1
    networks:
      - esnet
      - nginx_net

  nginx:
    image: "nginx:1.17.6-alpine"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - nginx_net


  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=chesno-node
      - cluster.name=chesno-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
      - 9301:9300
    networks:
      - esnet


volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local


networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge
  nginx_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Command `docker-compose docker-compose.yml exec elasticsearch1 curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` returns:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "chesno-cluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 22,
  "active_shards" : 22,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 22,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

The command utilizes only a fraction of machine's CPU and memory inside docker. Also, It has more shards comparing to the default elasticsearch setup for the project outside docker (that has only 5 shards).

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure this out? Having the same issue

Comment: Hi!  I used to mess with this setup so much that I don't remember how did I resolved this particular issue. Anyway, there are several issues I can spot out in my setup now. I'll post an answer with my current setup. Hope that will help

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember how I resolved this problem almost a year ago, but I have some ideas that might help. There are several problems with that setup:

1. [Official instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) describe a **multi-node cluster** that consists of three nodes. For single-node cluster you should specify  `discovery.type=single-node`. Single node cluster is suitable only for a development environment. For production, I suggest to leave docker and set up a multiple-server cluster with [ansilbe](https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch).
2. It's better to use a recent version of elasticsearch
3. There are too many shards

> A good practice is to ensure the amount of shards for each node stays below 20 per GB of heap that is configured.

Check out [this](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-specify-the-number-of-shards-and-number-of-replicas-per-shard-in-elasticsearch) tutorial to find out more.

4. Make sure that you have enough space on hard disk and don't receive an error `flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on`.

Here is my current setup for elasticsearch:

```
services:
 
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01_local
      - cluster.name=es_cluster_local
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
```

Command `docker-compose docker-compose.yml exec es01 curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` returns:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "es_cluster_local",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 6,
  "active_shards" : 6,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 6,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```